# Get the value of an object property dynamically

Tags: javascript

I want to get the value of an object property. For reasons I wont go in to, I need the function to be abstract so i can use it in different scenarios. Here's what I have:

```
function getPropertyValue(obj, prop){
    return obj.prop;
}

var obj = {
    name: "tom",
    age: 23
}

console.log('age is ');
console.log(getPropertyValue(obj, "age"));
```

This returns `underfined` because it's looking for the property "prop" on the object, which doesn't exist. How do I get it to look for the property passed as `prop`, e.g. if `"name"` is passed as `prop` it would look for `obj.name`?

The jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rvjf4e1t/)

Comment: its not `obj.prop` , refer properties using [square] brackets, like `obj[prop]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getPropertyValue(obj, prop){
    return obj[prop];
}

var obj = {
    name: "tom",
    age: 23
}

var name = getPropertyValue(obj,"name");
var age = getPropertyValue(obj,"age");
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply use bracket notation:

```
function getPropertyValue(obj, prop){
    return obj[prop];
}
```